# Metadata overhead warnings in couchbase web

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I have 3 node couchbase cluster which is working fine but now days I am getting many alerts as "Metadata overhead warning. Over 54% RAM allocated to bucket" on couchabse web UI. Please help to supress these alert

Comment: Might be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164029/couchbase-metadata-overhead-warning-62-ram-is-taken-up-by-keys-and-metadata